# CMake: Regenerate source file if target gets rebuilt

Tags: cmake, cmake-custom-command, add-custom-target

I am trying to embed the build date into a source file, so that every time a specific target gets built, the embedded date is refreshed, without regenerating every time the overall project built.

I.e. I have a header file `builddate.h` that is generated by a command that has a set of `#define`s. This header file is then included from other source files.

My first attempt was this:

```
add_custom_target(builddate COMMAND <command that generates header file>)
add_library(mylibrary ...)
add_dependencies(mylibrary builddate)
```

This correctly generates the header file, however the header file is generated every time, regardless of whether the `mylibrary` target needs to be rebuilt.

Trying with a custom command instead, i.e.

```
add_custom_command(OUTPUT builddate.h COMMAND <command that generates header file>)
add_library(mylibrary ... builddate.h)
```

correctly generates the header once, but if the `mylibrary` target is rebuilt, the header is not regenerated as `builddate.h` is already up to date.

This feels like something that should be reasonably common, but I cannot figure out what incantation of custom commands and targets will give me the desired effect. What I want is to call the command every time the `mylibrary` target is built, without spurious rebuilds if nothing has changed or if unrelated targets (such as executables using `mylibrary`) are built.

Using a `PRE_BUILD` custom command would sound like a good idea, but the docs state that this gets invoked just prior to `PRE_LINK` commands for generators other than Visual Studio, i.e. *after* sources are compiled. This seems like it would make this unsuitable for this purpose, as the header is needed while compiling the sources.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found an old thread at https://cmake.org/pipermail/cmake/2010-October/040247.html suggesting to call CMake's `--build` for a target as a `PRE_LINK` command:

```
# This is the library that I want to build
add_library(mylibrary ...)

# Set up a library that contains the code depending on the build date
# Use an OBJECT library because we don't need it to be a full static lib
# we just want to build some source that would "normally" have been part of mylibrary
add_library(builddate OBJECT EXCLUDE_FROM_ALL codethatusesbuilddate.cpp)

# Add a PRE_LINK command for mylibrary so that prior to linking we
# 1. Generate the builddate.h header
# 2. Call CMake to build the builddate library we just set up
add_custom_command(
    TARGET mylibrary PRE_LINK
    COMMAND <command that generates builddate.h>
    COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} --build ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR} --target builddate
)

# We also need to link with the library
# NOTE: uses the generator expression to link with the output files rather than the target
# to avoid CMake setting up a dependency from builddate to mylibrary which I think
# would cause builddate to be built prior to building mylibrary, but at that point we
# haven't generated the header yet. Which we could fix, but then we'd just build it twice
target_link_libraries(mylibrary PRIVATE $<TARGET_OBJECTS:builddate>)
```

This feels a little awkward, but it seems to work.

Footnote: Generating the header is easily done using CMake, i.e. first `configure_file` or similar to create a CMake script that does the generation, then invoke `${CMAKE_COMMAND} -P ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/generated_cmake_file.cmake` as the command to generate the header.

Answer (score 1):

Some time ago, I wrote a cmake makro. It adds custom command to generate version.cpp in current build directory by executing Cversion.cmake.
The generation of file is executed only when dependencies have changed.
With cmake-generator-expressions dependencies are set to dependencies of target minus its own (files).

It could be improved by adding libs dependencies to also generate anew version file.

```
macro(add_versioning T)
add_custom_command(OUTPUT "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/version.cpp"
        COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} "-DCMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR=${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}"
        -P "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/Version/CVersion.cmake"
        MAIN_DEPENDENCY "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/Version/version.cpp.in"
        DEPENDS "$<FILTER:$<TARGET_OBJECTS:${T}>,EXCLUDE,version.cpp.+$>")

target_include_directories(${T} PUBLIC "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/Version")
target_sources(${T} PUBLIC "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/Version/version.h" PRIVATE "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/version.cpp")

endmacro()
```